# How to make an executable file in Windows?

Tags: file, express, executable, shebang

I'm following an expressJS tutorial and the instructor creates the following  executable file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('./../app');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

This method of creating executable files (using the shebang) seems to only work in UNIX operating systems. Is there any simple way of getting the same result in Windows?

Comment: You just have to call `node name_of_your_js_file.js`

Comment: Thank you! I had completely forgotten that I could do that hah @Michael

Comment: Glad that it was that easy to solve

Answer (score 1):

Just call

```
node your_js_file_containg_the_snippet.js
```